# AWS android SDK NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run the following example using the AWS android SDK:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/SimpleDB_HighScores

I receive the following error when trying to add/remove/view an entry from the Android APP:

```
01-16 12:09:23.986: E/AndroidRuntime(23943): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
```

I have provided my Access Key ID and also my Secret Access Key from my AWS account on the code.

I have also linked all the necessary libraries.

Does anyone knows what is going on?

I have already googled the problem and the solutions provided on other answers do not work for me.

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot of your project setup? Also, have you previously used any third party libraries in Android?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Did you select to export the libraries when adding them to the project?

Comment: what do you mean with exporting the libraries?

Comment: Checkout out this [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx20QCGGQZLH23U/Running-AWS-SDK-for-Android-samples-in-Eclipse-with-ADT-v22) for details.